# How to convert str to date oparator in Python?

Tags: python, operators

I want to convert a string to datetime object. I have this code working good:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_str_now = str(input('Ingresar hora: '))
time_format = '%H:%M:%S'
time_now = datetime.strptime(time_str_now, time_format)
time_plus = int(input('Ingresar hora adicional: '))    

time_from_now = time_now + timedelta(minutes = time_plus)
fecha_hora = '{:%H:%M:%S}'.format(time_from_now)
print(fecha_hora)
```

This prints:

```
Ingresar hora: 00:00:00
Ingresar hora adicional: 45
00:45:00
```

Now, I want to provide an option to choose if the user want "hours", "minutes", "seconds" or "miliseconds". I tried this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_str_now = str(input('Ingresar hora: '))
time_format = '%H:%M:%S'
time_now = datetime.strptime(time_str_now, time_format)
time_plus = int(input('Ingresar hora adicional: '))

operador = str(input('Oparador: ')) #here is where the user shuld to select the input: hours, minutes, seconds, ...

time_from_now = time_now + timedelta(operador = time_plus) #here is where it should go: hours, minutes, seconds, ...
fecha_hora = '{:%H:%M:%S}'.format(time_from_now)
print(fecha_hora)
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Tatiana/Documents/Python Projects/Pruebas1.py", line 10, in <module>

   time_from_now = time_now + timedelta(operador = time_plus)

   TypeError: 'operador' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: What is the error you receive? It will also benefit in completing the question to put the input you give.

Comment: Sure, I receive this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tatiana/Documents/Python Projects/Pruebas1.py", line 10, in <module>
    time_from_now = time_now + timedelta(operador = time_plus)
TypeError: 'operador' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to parametrize the member to increment, you must unpack a param dict which key should be the kwarg to timedelta function

```
>>> from datetime import datetime,timedelta
>>> op='days'
>>> increment_value=1
>>> dt_now = datetime.now()
>>> dt_now + timedelta(**{op:increment_value})
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 15, 7, 40, 15, 519452)
```

This snippet it's equivalent to

```
>>> dt_now + timedelta(days = 1)
```

It's because the dict will be unpacked and each item will be translated as keyword argument of timedelta function

Comment: Please explain why this is a solution.

Comment: Ohh!! -xecgr- You gave the precise answer. This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @xecgr I invite you to answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25468319/how-to-extract-and-increment-the-hour-from-text-str-using-python