# How to extract and increment the hour from text (str) using Python

Tags: python, string, date-format

For example I have this text (Input):

```
Event Time, Monday:
10:01:02,269 to 10:01:08,702
(Reported by John).

Event Time, Sunday:
20:01:08,931 to 20:01:15,234
(Reported by Peter).

...
```

Then you want to alter and increase the time (only the time), thus (Output):

```
Event Time, Monday:
10:01:02,369 to 10:01:09,002 #Change the microseconds and seconds
(Reported by John).

Event Time, Sunday:
20:01:09,131 to 20:01:15,934 #Change the microseconds and seconds
(Reported by Peter).
```

Once I have the times, I can alter. So the problem is how to get only the times. I was thinking that maybe one way would be to collect the times in a list, like this:

```
times = ['10:01:02,269', '10:01:08,702', '20:01:08,931', '20:01:15,234']
```

But how to make that? and then, how to increase it in the list? And finally how to print without changing the text.

Comment: Do all the lines in the text have this regular pattern, or does it change?

Comment: Yes, all the lines have the regular pattern. The only thing that changes are the names of text.

Comment: If my answer helps, please confirm it so that anyone else could find this answer easily. Thanks!

Comment: @shx2 The only code I have is to increase the time, but one by one; as you already know. What I want to know a way to extract the time from a string. Maybe touring the string until finding a time format, but not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use pattern `'[0-9:,]'` to find all the time data.
2. `times.sort()` can increase time in the list
3. `print 'it time %s' % str(times[0])`  for instance, could print without changing the text